# Extract key value from json using javascript

Tags: javascript, extract

How can I console log **AMS Upgrade** and **BMS works**, note that these are variables, so the solution should not directly reference the above string value. i am successful in getting all values as per code below except for them.

**Code:**

```
const data = {"line_items": 
    {"AMS Upgrade": [
        {"Total": 30667.303111791967},
        {"complete": 1.0},
        {"claimed": 25799.788761888347}],
    "BMS works":    [
        {"Total": 35722.8761704046},
        {"complete": 0.1},
        {"claimed": 3572.2876170404597}]
    }
}
let totals = [];
for(let key in data.line_items){
  console.log(data['line_items'][1])
  console.log(data.line_items[key][0].Total)
  console.log(data.line_items[key][1].complete)
  console.log(data.line_items[key][2].claimed)

}
```

Comment: String values are not referenced.

Comment: i got it, console.log(key)

Comment: There's no JSON here. You only have JavaScript.

Comment: If you are using newer version of browser, try `console.table()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const data = {"line_items": 
    {"AMS Upgrade": [
        {"Total": 30667.303111791967},
        {"complete": 1.0},
        {"claimed": 25799.788761888347}],
    "BMS works":    [
        {"Total": 35722.8761704046},
        {"complete": 0.1},
        {"claimed": 3572.2876170404597}]
    }
}
let totals = [];
for(let key in data.line_items){
  console.log(key)
  console.log(data.line_items[key][0].Total)
  console.log(data.line_items[key][1].complete)
  console.log(data.line_items[key][2].claimed)

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You already have code that puts them in a variables:

> ```
> for (let key in data.line_items) {
> ```

Just log the value of `key`.

```js
const data = {
  "line_items": {
    "AMS Upgrade": [{
        "Total": 30667.303111791967
      },
      {
        "complete": 1.0
      },
      {
        "claimed": 25799.788761888347
      }
    ],
    "BMS works": [{
        "Total": 35722.8761704046
      },
      {
        "complete": 0.1
      },
      {
        "claimed": 3572.2876170404597
      }
    ]
  }
}
let totals = [];
for (let key in data.line_items) {
  console.log(key);
}
```